# Mysql Count to return zero if no match

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a set of approx 9000 tutor ids in an array and i have put them in a string like:

```
(1,2, 3, 4,5,6,7,....9000,9001,9002)
```

so that i can use them in the following query:

```
select count(student_assignment.assignment_id) as total_assignment from 
student_assignment, assigned_tutor_fk where  assignment_status = 'closed'
 and assigned_tutor_fk in (1,2, 3, 4,5,6,7,..100,101,103...9000,9001,9002)
 group by assigned tutor_fk.
```

I want to calculate total number of rows associated with each tutor(assigned_tutor_fk), and those tutors which do not have an assignment ie those which do not have assignment 
record in the table i want to show their assignment count as 0, and i just want my query to return count and assigned_tutor_fk
my table structure is:

```
    assignment_id | assigned_tutor_fk | assignment_date | student_id |
    |    1        |   2               |  22-01-2011     |  4         |
    |    2        |   3               |  14-03-2011     |  5         |
```

Im trying to get my output to be like this:

```
    |total_assignment | assigned_tutor_fk |
    |      5          | 4                 |
    |      2          | 7                 |
    |      0          | 8                 |
```

Update: I tthink i have not been able to express myself properly,i already have a list of tutors filtered on another criteria, it was very complex to combine these two queries so now i have a set of the tutor id's and  i want the sum to be displayed as zero in case the tutors does not have assignment record. please help me on this as i don know wht to do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.id, COUNT(sa.assignment_id)
FROM    tutor t
LEFT JOIN
        student_assignement sa
ON      sa.assignment_tutor_fk = t.id
WHERE   t.id IN (1, 2, ..., 9002)
GROUP BY
        t.id
```

Comment: but i already have a list of tutors filtered on another criteria now i have a set of the tutor id's and further more i want the sum o be displayed as zero i case the tutors does not have assignment record

Comment: thank u this solved my problem, i admit at first i did not tink itr was suitable but then i realised it was the best possible solution in this situation..thanks u made may day!! cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as total_assignment,
  assigned_tutor_fk  
FROM assignmentTable 
GROUP BY assigned_tutor_fk
```

Comment: Might do it like this to get the result set he wants: SELECT count(*) AS total_assignment, assigned_tutor_fk FROM assignmentTable GROUP BY assigned_tutor_fk

Comment: i tried it before but it only gives the result of those tutors which have a record in the table, it does not return zero where no match is found..

Comment: @MahmoudGamal `IFNULL` won't work... in this case there isn't a row returned with a `NULL` count... instead, there's just no row returned at all...

Answer (score 0):

dont put the tutors in a string. Select them from a table and do a LEFT JOIN with the assignment and FK table. Without knowing all of your tables, i'm guessing it would look like this:

```
select 
   t.tutorId,
   count(sa.assignment_id) as total_assignment
from 
   tutor t
LEFT JOIN
   assigned_tutor_fk fk
ON
   fk.assigned_tutor_fk = tutor.tutorId 
LEFT JOIN
   student_assignment sa
ON
  fk.assignment_id = sa.id
where  
   sa.assignment_status = 'closed' OR
   ISNULL(sa.assignment_status) -- if join fails.
group by 
   t.tutorId
```

`Left Join` retrieves all your values from the tutor table and merges it with the joined table IF there is a match. If not, NULL is inserted.