# Expect count 0 when no records found for a value

Tags: sql

I have two tables, A and B. Table A has list of students. Table B has their datewise attendance. I am checking which student was present for how many classes. I get no records for students that were never present. I want to get their records with a 0 against their name. Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT StudentName, Count(*) 
FROM Students, Attendance
WHERE Students.StudentID = Attendance.StudentID
GROUP BY StudentName
```

I already checked the answer to question posted in [Mysql Count to return zero if no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337514/mysql-count-to-return-zero-if-no-match)
I tried using left join as given in the solution but I still get the same results. Student that never figured in attendance sheet do not show up in the query results. I want to see their names with count 0 against their name.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using `left outer join` as below -

```
SELECT StudentName, Count(Attendance.StudentID) 
FROM Students left outer join Attendance
on (Students.StudentID = Attendance.StudentID)
GROUP BY StudentName
```

**Edit**

as per very valid point highlighted by bendataclear I have changed `count(*)` expression with `count(Attendance.StudentID)`.
Now how it will work, if suppose our case where we want to get `0` as total for student where they don't have any entry in attendance  table, for those left outer join output will have null value in attendance.studentID column and when we'll try to count for this column it will return zero for those student.

**Edit 2**

case -  where we need to have condition on classID also (from attendance table)

```
  SELECT studentname, COUNT(attendance.studentid)
    FROM students
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE classid IN ('X', 'XI', 'XII')) 
                 AS Attendance 
      ON (students.studentid =attendance.studentid)
   GROUP BY studentname
```

I think this could solve your problem.

Comment: `Count(*)` will return greater than 0 for all students in the student table, you want to count a field in the left joined table to get a count of matching rows (eg `Count(Attendance.StudentID)`)

Comment: Thank you Pratik and Ben! This solved my basic problem but a question still remains. In order to simply the query, I had removed specific students and specific classes I was running this query for. If I remove the where clause, I get all results correctly, however, if I add a where clause and specify the list of students I query for and the list of classes I am querying for, I miss out on rows where count is 0.. any suggestions on that?

Comment: if you are taking condition on attendance table with class column, where respective class is not there then you will not get any row from this table result you will not get any result from that table itself.

Comment: For that you may use that condition in subqyery in place of attendance table.
please see my updated answer\

Comment: Also, LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN seem to give same results?

Comment: Thanks Pratik, that helps but what if I have specific students to pick and not all students? I am struggling to get the grammar right in case of that.. thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jitendra for student you can have condition in where clause.
but for class (which all are not available) if you put condition it will not give you desired output.

Comment: @Jitendra why you unaccepted this answer.
Means you accepted first and then unaccepted??

Comment: The join and the internal sub query gave me a solution but it didnt solve my problem of querying for specific students list. Sorry, I didn't mean to reject the solution, although, the reason I removed the checkmark is just because I wish to get the other part correct and then update the comments. I got stuck in some urgent work and hence haven't worked on that yet. I hope to get it covered in a day or two..

Comment: Just gave it quick try before leaving for the day. It worked!! The filter for students part was used in where clause and it just worked fine! I was trying to use it in the earlier query and hence was getting wrong answer. Thanks much Pratik! My problem is solved now! My day ends well!!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the `isnull` on the `classes` column (that's my name - not yours), but it definitely works in Sql Server:-

```
create table #students (
    studentid int,
    studentname varchar(50)
)
insert into #students values 
    (1,'david smith'),
    (2,'somebody else'),
    (3,'another person')

create table #attendance (
    studentid int,
    attendedon date
)
insert into #attendance values
     (1,'2013-01-01'),
     (3,'2013-01-01'),
     (3,'2013-01-02')

select s.studentname, isnull(a.classes,0) as classes
from #students s
left join (
    select studentid, count(*) as classes
    from #attendance
    group by studentid
) a on a.studentid=s.studentid
order by s.studentname
```

returns:-

```
studentname     classes
another person  2
david smith     1
somebody else   0
```

Comment: This answer pre-dates the addition of MySQL to the question - I have no idea if this syntax works in MySQL - but I'll leave it here for anyone that stumbles by looking for a Microsoft solution.

Comment: Thank you David, however I am getting syntax errors on this and I couldn't try it out :(. I am using MS SQL. The first solution provided above solves my initial problem. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: my solution is sql server specific.  are you sure you aren't using MySQL?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2005... I may have misunderstood the syntax?

Comment: weird.  the question is tagged with MySQL, which caused my confusion. I can't see anything in my answer that would cause a syntax error... but without your schema it's difficult to test.  I'll have another look and see whether I've gone mad...

Comment: I am so sorry. I don't recall if and how I had added MySQL tag. sorry about that. I removed it. I had simplified the context of my problem with this example. I also need to check if I made some mistake in converting the code.

Comment: I've updated my answer (and added a vital `isnull`) and checked it works in sql server.

Comment: I think you have SQL 2008 or later. I am using 2005 and some of the syntax has changed since... Thanks for your help anyway. I am checking the syntax that works. Thank you very much.

Comment: derived tables and isnull() exist in Sql Server 2005 - there's nothing else in my code...

Comment: I was getting errors in trying your code before implementing. Since the multiple values addition wasn't working I couldn't test it straightaway :). The solution Pratik gave above, including the subquery part helped me fix my query issue. Although I had to add the "isnull" function you suggested. Thanks very much for your help!